# How to make a contingency table from categorical data using Python?

Tags: python, scipy, categorical-data, contingency

I have a sample dataset as below

```
  Phillippines  Indonesia   Malta       India
0   Error Free  Error Free  Defective   Error Free
1   Error Free  Error Free  Error Free  Defective
2   Error Free  Defective   Defective   Error Free
3   Error Free  Error Free  Error Free  Error Free
4   Error Free  Error Free  Defective   Error Free
```

I want to make a contingency table with row index as Defective, Error Free and column index as  Phillippines, Indonesia,    Malta,  India and data as their corresponding value counts. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi think you are looking for below result.

```
data_crosstab = pd.crosstab([df['Phillippines'], df['Indonesia'], df['Malta'], df['India']], 'result')
```

above code will give you the following result.

[image]

Hope it will solve!!

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for answering, but I am looking for contingency table.

Comment: Not understood it is a contingency table. give me sample output if you can or what is wrong with above.

Comment: Hi.. I want contingency table like this one for example http://www.mathandstatistics.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/EyeColorContTable.jpg

Comment: HI @Vaitybharati please take look this one I think you are looking for this. maybe you need to change your data like he explains.
https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_crosstabs/

Comment: I was able to find solution using value_counts() pandas code. But had to individually apply it to all columns and then prepare contingency table in array format.. I am looking for direct code..Thanks